# Has anyone tried to make 3-D chess in real life?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, the-big-bang-theory

In addition to seeing it played on TOS and TNG, I saw Sheldon and Leonard play three-dimensional chess on an episode of the *Big Bang Theory* and it got me curious.

Has anyone ever tried to make or adapt this 3-D chess game in the real world?

[image]

Comment: @user14111 - Behind the scenes questions are on-topic. There's several areas of interest here; The rules of the game, whether there were rules when Star Trek was originally written, where the specific set in TBBT came from. All of those are perfectly fine for the site

Comment: @user14111 - I put that one down to OPs use of English. There's more than enough meat here to make the question broadly topical, even if elements of it might be asked elsewhere. I've changed the wording slightly (from *a* 3D chess game to *this* 3D chess game)

Comment: I remember reading a set of rules  for 3d chess and creating board and pieces some time in the early 1950s. There was an archbishop who moved on all the diagonals.  I've no reference.

Comment: @EthanBolker There have bneen many versions of 3D chess a.k.a. "space chess". The one with an "archbishop" was invented by Dr. Ervand Kogbetliantz. Quoting D. R. Pritchard's *Encyclopedia of Chess Variants*: "First developed in Russia, where Kogbetliantz was living at the time, the game was launched in the U.S. in 1952 where it received a lot of publicity (*Newsweek, Time, New Yorker,* etc.)"

Comment: While not specifically 3D, I'd suggest looking at [List of Chess variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_variants).  There are several mentions of 3D arrangements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a word, yes. Paramount (the makers of Star Trek) have licenced [various Tri-D chess sets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D5CXMAO) through the [Franklin Mint company](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0018S4WM0) and more recently through through their [own production house](https://paramountshop.com/products/star-trek-tridimensional-chess-set). These come with a [Star Trek certificate of authenticity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTPFJ.jpg) as well as a complete set of rules developed by Franz Joseph and Andrew Bartmess in the 1970s.

> The Tri-D chessboard was further realized by its inclusion in the Star
> Trek [Star Fleet Technical Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Star_Fleet_Technical_Manual) (1975) by Franz Joseph, who created starting positions for the pieces and short, additional rules.

[image]

> The complete Standard Rules for the game were originally developed in 1976 by Andrew Bartmess (with encouragement from Joseph) and were subsequently expanded by him into a [commercially available booklet](http://www.yestercade.net/get.htm).
>
> <sub><sup>[Wikipedia: 3D Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_chess#cite_ref-13)</sup></sub>

---

The set [seen on *The Big Bang Theory*](https://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/blueshift/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/7048722785_4007ab0f46.jpg) is a reproduction, likely of the [50th Anniversary edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D5CXMAO) based on the colours. The set they bought was incorrectly sized, according to the show's prop master and they needed to scale it up for camera.

> **Scott:** Well, I’m the property master on the show and basically it’s anything an actor touches, from the rings, watches, food, guns,
> their computers, the chemicals, the experiments they do on the set.
> The wacky games they play. **I built the 3D chess set – the actual one
> we bought was just too small. It was like on a Friday run-through and
> Chuck [Lorre, executive producer and co-creator] goes, “It’s really
> good. But can we have one, like, three times the size by Monday?” I
> literally built it.** If you look at them, they kind of have this curve
> that holds the three levels. So I went and I got a globe stand that
> has the same curve and then I built it off that. So we just worked all
> weekend long and had it for them.
>
> <sub><sup>[A talk with Scott London, property master for The Big Bang Theory](https://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/blueshift/index.php/2012/04/10/maggies-blog-a-talk-with-scott-london-propmaster-for-the-big-bang-theory/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

There are many rules for 3D chess, but the one from *Star Trek* has been adapted into a real set of rules called “Tridimensional Chess”. (which is what Leonard and Sheldon are playing in that episode)

I would suspect that the chess set seen in the *Big Bang Theory* is  actually a commercially produced Tridimensional Chess Set.

Comment: "*I would suspect that the chess set seen in the Big Bang Theory is actually a commercially produced Tridimensional Chess Set* - You would suspect wrong. That thing is huge

Comment: @Valorum: I was wondering: the episode I thought of and pulled up when this was answered was the later series episode where Sheldon gets a box out of the cupboard that is a generic cardboard box with what appears to be a piece of letter paper that says “Star Trek 3D Chess” taped to it. But they don’t actually get the set out  and play it in that episode, so I thought maybe they produced that prop at short notice, and they had the real thing in earlier episodes.

Comment: It actually enhances that scene to know that their set is both comically oversized and not the real thing, hence the crappy box with the wrong name in it.

Comment: Lots of things on TV shows are outsized or weird-looking if you actually think about them. The corridors on starships are massive, as are doorways.